# How to handle two Maven submodules that share a code dependency

Tags: maven, log4j

I have what I think is a fairly common setup. I have a project with two modules, each with its own pom.xml. Above that, I have a pom.xml for the project, which depends upon its submodules. The two submodules have a shared dependency, namely log4j. How should I deal with this dependency? Should I simply just have each submodule have log4j as a dependency, or should the higher level project module get involved, claiming it as a project dependency? If I have both submodules listing the dependency, will Maven be smart and only pull down log4j once, or will each submodule pull down its own private copy of log4j ? If the project module has the dependency, will the log4j package be available at the right time for the submodules? What would you do, or what have you done in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is with the [dependencyManagement](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) tag.

> The dependency management section is a mechanism for centralizing dependency information. When you have a set of projects that inherits a common parent it's possible to put all information about the dependency in the common POM and have simpler references to the artifacts in the child POMs.

To summarize the effect, you put the tag in the parent pom and have the children refer to it.  They don't refer to the version number though.  The benefit is at any time you can update the version of log4j in the parent pom and all your child poms get the new version without modifying their poms.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Maven. I knew there was a way to do it, I just didn't know what it was. I notice that there's a new way now, too, that involves importing dependencies rather than inheriting. I'm going to look at that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to set the dependency at the higher level project. This will cover the dependency for both modules of your project.

Source: This is what my team does in one of our projects.